# Composite video on Compute Module

Tags: hardware, composite-video, compute-module

I'm working on a Compute Module design that uses the composite video output. I know the Zero and presumably the full size Pi have some passive components on the output pin, but I'm not sure what of that is included on the Compute Module. Do I just need to bring TVDAC and ground to a connector, or is there more circuitry that I need in between (termination resistors, etc)?

This should be a simple test, but I unfortunately don't have a CMIO board on hand to try with. Hypothetically, one should be able attach an RCA connector just like the Zero but the documentation is sorely lacking with respect to this feature on the CM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon diving into the schematic of the compute module itself, the 15 Ohm termination resistor that's also present on the Zero is in fact included on the CM.

[image: CM3+ DAC]